# Moving Files in Hadoop using API

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Is it possible to move files in hadoop using the `FileSystem` class https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For a MapReduce copy that is faster than `hadoop fs -cp`, look at the [`DistCp` source code](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/tools/DistCp.html)

Or if you actually want to move a file [`hadoop fs -mv` source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/MoveCommands.java#L86-L117) . Note: "move" is actually a "rename" in HDFS.

[`FileSystem#rename`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#rename(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) is what you want.

Comment: would you happen to have an example using the API?

Comment: I don't have an example from code... My point is that all the `hadoop fs` and `hdfs` commands are using the Java API under the scene, so therefore the basis of your question is that yes, it is possible because that's what you are already doing otherwise with a shell script.